# How do I add up values of buttons in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to sum up values of buttons if the buttons are clicked on. For example, there is "Button1". If this button is clicked, it should add its value to a sum which will be displayed at the bottom of the page. If "Button1" is clicked a second time it should substract its value from the sum.

Here is my attempt to do this but it's not doing anything at all:

```
var value_Buttons = 0;
var total = 0;

$("button[name=Button1],[name=Button2],[name=Button3],[name=Button4],[name=Button5],[name=Button6]").click(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('active') == false) {
        value_Buttons += parseInt($(this).val());
    } else if($(this).hasClass('active') == true) {
        value_Buttons -= parseInt($(this).val());
    }
    total += value_Buttons;
    alert(total);
});

total = value_Buttons + value_Optional_Button;
$("input[name=value_sum]").val(total);
```

Additionally, here is the code for an examplary button (Like "Button1"):

```
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
    <button type="button" class="form-control btn btn-primary" name="Button1" value="300" title="300 €" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off">Button 1</button>
</div>
```

There will be more buttons, but they will only differ in their name and value.

Also, the box which will display the sum of the button-values currently looks like this:

```
<div>
    <label class="control-label">Sum</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input class="form-control" name="value_sum" style="text-align:right" id="costs" value="" type="text" readonly>
        <span class="input-group-addon">&euro;</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've searched all over Stackoverflow, as well as via Google, etc. yet I can't find anything or anyone with a similar problem

Comment: Start by replacing all button tags with classes. It saves code and is more readable. Also you can use this do give the buttons some 'state'.

Comment: The button either has the class, or it doesn't - there's no need for the `if` clause on the `else` branch.

Comment: you also appear to have a problem in that it's not specified what happens if a button is pressed zero times, or 3+.   As written zero presses still makes it go negative, when perhaps that button should be ignored entirely?

Comment: It seems to me normal that zero press does nothing :) if you click 3 times, you add, substract, re-add (according to OP)

Comment: @sodawillow sure, except that most of the answers (and the question) only permit two states - `class="active"`, or not.   Doing nothing for zero presses requires three states.

Comment: Not sure but I think you miss the point : the code is ONLY ran if user clicks on the button :) --- [sorry if I misunderstood you]

Comment: @sodawillow no, it's me (too tired).  I thought the OP was accumulating the total every time based entirely on the current DOM state, and failed to notice the external running total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blocking JS logic error is here :

```
$("input[name=value_sum]").val(total);
```

this line should be in the above code block. Added corrections for substraction :

```js
var total = 0;

$("button[name]").on("click", function() {
    
    if(!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
        total += Number($(this).val());
        $(this).addClass('active').html("remove " + $(this).attr("title"));
    } else {
        total -= Number($(this).val());
        $(this).removeClass('active').html("add " + $(this).attr("title"));
    }
    
    $("input[name=value_sum]").val(total);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
    <button type="button" class="form-control btn btn-primary" name="Button300" value="300" title="300 €" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off">add 300 €</button>
    <button type="button" class="form-control btn btn-primary" name="Button600" value="600" title="600 €" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off">add 600 €</button>
</div>
<div>
    <label class="control-label">Sum</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input class="form-control" name="value_sum" style="text-align:right" id="costs" value="0" type="text" readonly>
        <span class="input-group-addon">&euro;</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lines 14 and 15 need to be placed within the click event of the button to update the value_sum input on every click. Also your selection for the value attribute it a little bit off. The way to return the value attribute of a button using jQuery is:

```
$(this).attr('value');
```

So after these two points, stripping your code of the if and else check, and also selecting the buttons with a cleaner method, you should have something like this:

```
var total = 0;

$("button[name=Button1], button[name=Button2], button[name=Button3], button[name=Button4], button[name=Button5], button[name=Button6]").click(function() {
    total += $(this).attr('value');
    $("input[name=value_sum]").val(total);
});
```

To display the total, that is 0, in the input element on page load, you could use:

```
<input class="form-control" name="value_sum" style="text-align:right" id="costs" value="0" type="text" readonly>
```

Comment: Much cleaner code. But no substraction if the user clicks again :)

Comment: Oh yes! I got caught up in trimming it down ~too much~ and forgot OP's point about adding and subtracting. So OP, keep the if/else check in there! Thanks @sodawillow

Comment: Yeah it looks great. For clarify, I would also add the value of 0 to the input element 'form-control'. And although the Number function isn't necessary, there's also the alternative of `total += ~~$(this).val();` instead of `total += Number($(this).val());` if OP knows that he's always going to be using whole integers.

Comment: Done a second ago :) thx and you're kinda right about `Number` but user can trick the values in html code before clicking :)

Answer (score 0):

start off by create a listener for a class that will be applied to all of your buttons.

```
$(.btn).click(function() {
  //get value
  var value = parseint($(this).attr("value"));
  //check if already clicked
  if($(this).hasClass('active') {
    //set value of total
    total = total - value;
    //remove class active
    $(this).removeClass('active');
  }else {
    //set value of total
    total = total + value;
    //addclass active
    $(this).addClass('active');
  }
)};
```

Is this what you need?

Comment: Typo : `var value = parseint($(this).arrt("value"));`

Comment: @sodawillow I fixed it, just a mistype.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hbkftfkt/5/).

Add as many buttons as you like, the only thing is that you'll have to add a data-value to them to figure out how much to add or substract. I would also do the search for buttons using a class instead of "button" but that's up to you.

```
var buttons = {};
$("button").each(function (index, item) {
    buttons[index] = 0;
    $(item).click(function () {
        var value = +($(item).data("value")),
            val = +($("#costs").val());

        val += (!buttons[index]) ? value : -value;
        buttons[index] = (!buttons[index]) ? 1: 0;

        $("#costs").val(val);
    });
});
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

## **[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dd8jd1se/1/)**

Here have added a classname 'add' for all buttons , on click its toggle class **add, sub** in you case you using **active,inactive** class

```
var total = 0;
$("button[name=button1],[name=button2],[name=button3]").on('click', function () {
    var self = $(this);
    var gValue = Number(self.val());
    if (self.hasClass("add")) {
        total += gValue;
        self.removeClass("add").addClass("sub");
    } else {
        total -= gValue;
        self.removeClass("sub").addClass("add");
    }
    $("#costs").val(total);
});
```